# Post ajax does not work in IOS and MacOs devices

Tags: php, ajax, cookies

I am working on a registration system for this site: bottlesbeach.eu Basically, when a user registers or logs in, a cookie is created and within this cookie there is a randomly generated string that will also be inserted in the mysql database in the user section table. **When you click Logout, the cookie should be cleared and the random string inside the mysql database** (the string session id) **should be cleared, this action of deleting the cookie and session string in the mysql db I did it using an Ajax post.**

Index.php onclick log-out:

```
     <?php 
    $logged = false;
    if (isset($_COOKIE["sessionid"])){
        $logged = true;
    
        ?> 
        <script>
       console.log("status: Logged");
    var ahr = document.getElementById('ahr');
    ahr.setAttribute('href', '');
    ahr.innerHTML="Log-out";
    ahr.onclick = function remokecookies() {
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: '/ajax.php',
           data:{action:'removecks'},
           cache: false,
      });
    }
  window.onload = function() {
    if(!window.location.hash) {
        window.location = window.location + '#logged';
        window.location.reload();
        
    }
}

    
        </script>
        
        <?
```

(Obviously I inserted a reload because otherwise the button text remained as "log-out" even if the ajax function was executed, and therefore the cookie was deleted.)

In the index I created a condition, if the cookie is there, it means that you are logged in, then at the top right there will be the log out button with the respective onclick ajax function that I showed previously. Otherwise it will be written login and clicking on it will take you to the login panel.

Ajax function (ajax.php):

```
    <?php
if($_POST['action'] == 'removecks') {
setcookie("sessionid", "", time() - 86400 * 30);
$hostname="";
  $username="";
  $password="";
  $dbname="";
  $ckvalue = $_COOKIE["sessionid"];
$conn = new mysqli($hostname,$username, $password, $dbname); 
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  ?> <script> console.log("Connection to db failed");</script><?
}
            $query = "UPDATE users SET sessionid = '' WHERE sessionid = '$ckvalue'";           
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $sessionid);
            $stmt->execute();  
}

?>
```

**Everything seems to work in the desktop version, but from mobile (only on apple devices), the "log-out" button remains.** So, I assume that **the ajax function is not executed, and the cookie is not cleared.** Would anyone know how to help me?

Comment: You would need to replace the location AFTER tha Ajax call is made. But it is unclear why you are not just setting the hash direclty which does not require a reload.

Comment: @epascarello what does it mean that I have to replace the position?

Comment: @epascarello how do i set up the hash that requires reloading?

Comment: I just did this and it still doesn't work